# Adapter with Fragment is not working at Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am new at Android. I am trying to show a simple forecast from a String array in the app using adapter on fragment. It is not appearing on the window. I have defined 2 classes (MainActivity and MainActivityFragment). I am using Android Studio 2.1.3.

- If I use fragment instead of ListView at activity_mail.xml  it gives me a stackoverflow error.
- If I use ListView at activity_mail.xml it doesn't appear.

Any help, will be really appreciate

Here is my code:

a) MainActivity.java

```
    package app.com.example.android.sunshine3;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

b) MainActivityFragment.java

```
    package app.com.example.android.sunshine3;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;


    public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));


        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forescast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        // Inflate the root layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;

    }
    }
```

c) activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.example.android.sunshine3.MainActivity">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="app.com.example.android.sunshine3.MainActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

d) list_item_forescast.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't really using your fragment because you aren't adding it in your `activity`. A simple fix would be to define an independent layout for your activity as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, within your activity add the `fragment` to this container:

```
setContentView(R.layout.home_activity_layout);

MainActivityFragment myFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, MainActivityFragment.class.getName()).commit();
```

That should do it.

Comment: Many thanks, Shaishav, but when I run it, It says:  Error:(16, 43) error: no suitable method found for add(int,MainActivityFragment,String)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual argument MainActivityFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @JoseGallo Make sure you `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` and not `import android.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: Hi @Shaishav, yes I have "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;"

Comment: @JoseGallo Try getting rid of the part `MainActivityFragment.class.getName()` in `add()`

Comment: @JoseGallo I'm sorry, its my bad. I should've seen you aren't using support fragment. Instead of `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` use `import android.app.FragmentManager;` and change `getSupportFragmentManager();` to `getFragmentManager();`.

Comment: thanks again @Shaishav, but It gives to me: Error:(17, 43) error: no suitable method found for add(int,MainActivityFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument MainActivityFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual argument int cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)

Comment: @JoseGallo yeah, once you remove support fragment usage, you should use the method described above. So, you need to re-include `MainActivityFragment.class.getName()`

Comment: thanks @Shaishav, now throws this: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.com.example.android.sunshine3/app.com.example.android.sunshine3.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: @JoseGallo So, now our fragment is finally running :) To fix this [type of] error, just get rid of the line `android:name="app.com.example.android.sunshine3.MainActivityFragment"` in your `<ListView>` in your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @JoseGallo I'll need to debug the code then as I can't find the error in above code. Can you share your project over dropbox, google drive or something.

Comment: many thanks @Shaishav for your effort! you can get the code here https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxrusUNIREWrS1NfVjAySzFEdkU&usp=sharing

Comment: @JoseGallo Found some referential errors: in your `MainActivity`, you need `setContentView(R.layout.independent_layout);` (you forgot this), in your `MainActivityFragment`, you need `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);` (you were referencing wrong layout) and finally in the same class, initialise your `ListView` as `ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);`

Comment: It should be running now

Comment: Many thanks!! @Shaishav it worked. Really appreciate it. Best Regards

Comment: @JoseGallo Cool...happy coding!